# Copy names from a table and list in separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a dataset that looks like such:

| Names | Orders |
| --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | 3 |
| Charlie Jones | 1 |

I want to copy the names and list them out in a separate sheet like so:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | row |
| Bob Smith | row |
| Bob Smith | row |
| Charlie Jones | row |

I'm new to this and trying to put together a list for a giveaway for work. thank you for your help.

I tried =arrayformula(rept(.... but it didn't list out how i thought it would

Answer (score 0):

You may try-

```
=REDUCE("Names",B2:B3,LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,MAP(SEQUENCE(x,1,1,0),LAMBDA(t,INDEX(A:A,ROW(x)))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
=arrayformula(tocol(split(rept(A2:A&"|",B2:B),"|"),3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("", REPT(A2:A&CHAR(10), B2:B)), CHAR(10))))
```

You may try Basically